# Using same javascript function to change preview of multiple image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have written code which allows user to upload multiple file upload :

```
<asp:Image ID="image01" runat="server" Width="20%" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/resourceContent/resaleContent/altImage.png';"/>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="image01_update" runat="server" onchange="showPreview(this);"/>
                                        <asp:Image ID="image02" runat="server" Width="20%" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/resourceContent/resaleContent/altImage.png';"/>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="image02_update" runat="server" onchange="showPreview(this);"/>
                                        <asp:Image ID="image03" runat="server" Width="20%" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/resourceContent/resaleContent/altImage.png';"/>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="image03_update" runat="server" onchange="showPreview(this);"/>
                                        <asp:Image ID="image04" runat="server" Width="20%" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/resourceContent/resaleContent/altImage.png';"/>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="image04_update" runat="server" onchange="showPreview(this);"/>
```

The javascript function which shows preview for uploaded image is as follows :

```
function showPreview(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#image01').css('visibility', 'visible');
                $('#image01').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

currently preview is working for first image upload only, as i am passing ID- #image01.

I want to use same javascript function to show preview for all four image uploaders.
i.e. when i upload first image from #image01, it must show it's preview, for 2nd it must show 2nd image's preview.. and so on....

NOTE : i am using image upload in form editing mode, if there is no image uploaded ,

```
onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/resourceContent/resaleContent/altImage.png';"
```

this code will show an alternate image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showPreview(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $(input).prev().css('visibility', 'visible');
                $(input).prev().attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use "data-" propery on button like this.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="image01"></div>
    <button data-id="#image01" id="testBtn">Press me</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#testBtn', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $(id).text('testim');
    });
```